# Reset --hard origin/master not bringing me to origin/master~HEAD?

Tags: git, github

I'm on the master branch with no local changes.

`git remote -v` lists the correct URL for fetch and push.

`git branch -avv` (after `git fetch`) shows remote/origin/master to be at an old out-of-date commit, which isn't where it *actually* is if you look at the repo on GitHub.
   `git reset --hard origin/master` puts me to that out-of-date commit.
`git diff --name-only origin/master` then comes up clean.

When I manually inspect the files in the file explorer at this point, they are indeed very behind....in the state they were in months ago. Not at all up to date with where origin/master is on GitHub.

`git pull --rebase` brings me to the *real* newest commit, which is where origin/master *actually* is at, if I go look at it on GitHub, but then `git diff --name-only origin/master` shows every file changed because it seems to be comparing against the old out-of-date commit.

I'm **so** confused.

Comment: What does `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` show?

Comment: Apparently, your fetch settings are incorrect, causing the remote branch `origin/master` not to update. `.git/config` should have a line `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` for your remote.

Comment: @torek No output from that command.

Comment: OK, that confirms the problem (although I'm not sure how you got *into* this state).

Comment: Remove your remote using `git remote remove origin` and then add it again using `git remote add origin git@github.com/user/project`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `git fetch` is not working is that the `fetch` setting under `remote.origin.fetch` is missing.  (How it got this way, I have no idea.)

When you run `git fetch`, your git contacts their git (GitHub, in this case) and asks for a list of all references (branches, tags, etc.—you can see what's available by running `git ls-remote origin`).  Then, given the resulting list, your git copies references as listed by the `fetch` setting.

Since your `fetch` setting is empty, your git matches zero references, and copies all zero of them (i.e., doesn't copy anything) and then exits, leaving `origin/master` unchanged.

(The `pull` script uses traces `fetch` leaves behind in `FETCH_HEAD` and is therefore able to rebase.)

To fix it, restore the default `fetch` setting, e.g.:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

(spelling is important here, so I hope I have not made any typos).  Or, you can instead delete and re-add `origin`, as [poke suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427283/reset-hard-origin-master-not-bringing-me-to-origin-masterhead?noredirect=1#comment45189052_28427283).

Comment: Everytime I think I'm getting good with git, something like this happens. All is well now, but for one last thing: `git branch -avv` still shows remote/origin/master in red, as if it's not up to date, despite fetching. Would you happen to know what that means?

Comment: I mean....it shows the correct commit for both the local and origin master branches....I'm just wondering if the red on the origin/master means git believes something is not up-to-date.

Comment: I'm not sure if these colors default the same way everywhere, but for me, git uses black or green for local branches (green for the one HEAD refers to, if any), and red for remote branches.  These are (definitely) configurable, with `color.branch.<slot>` as described in git-config.